# how to merge 2 columns in hive?

Tags: hive

My output for certain query is

> 1          null
>
> 2         null
>
> null       3
>
> null        4

Where as my output should be

> 1    3
>
> 2    4

How can I make it happen?

Any help would be great!

Comment: Are you joining two tables and then doing the select ?
Also please give the table structure and a snippet of data set you are using.

Comment: No. Not two tables.. My scenario is that I have a column ID, Event as IN /OUT.. And another column data and time.. I have to created the in time and out time for a particular ID.. so my output should have

ID      IN TIME OUT TIME
1           10     11
2           12      13

Instead I am getting

1    10  null
2    12  null
1    null 11
2    null 13

Answer (score 1):

So what I understand, this is your data set:

```
1   10      NULL
1   NULL    11
2   20      NULL
2   NULL    25
11  110     NULL
11  NULL    111
12  120     NULL
12  NULL    125
```

And this is your output set:

```
1   10  11
2   20  25
11  110 111
12  120 125
```

Here's the query that will help to give the required output:

```
select in.id,in.in_time,out.out_time from(
select id, min(in_time) as in_time from time_table 
  where in_time is not null group by id) in 
join ( 
select id, max(out_time) as out_time from time_table where out_time is not null group by id) out on (in.id = out.id)
```

I am doing a self join in the table and getting the required columns.

Hope it helps...!!!

Comment: OK.. Thank you so much.. I will try this out.. Also I have one more query.. Now some records are incomplete.. like there is IN time but no OUT time.. and vice versa.. How can I ignore such records?

Comment: you added Distinct right? I tried that also.. still its giving me many combinations also extra records.

Comment: 10743   01:25:37.257    01:27:40.257
10743   01:25:37.240    01:27:40.257
10743   04:33:25.344    01:27:40.257
10743   19:02:49.247    01:27:40.257
10743   01:25:37.257    01:27:41.200
10743   01:25:37.240    01:27:41.200
10743   04:33:25.344    01:27:41.200
10743   19:02:49.247    01:27:41.200
16300   01:24:45.350    01:27:45.257
19543   09:13:41.812    04:14:43.513
16374   04:14:43.513    04:33:25.343
16374   17:01:34.602    04:33:25.343
16374   19:21:19.701    04:33:25.343
10743   01:25:37.257    09:13:27.660

Comment: This was my initial output
10743   01:25:37.257    NULL
16300   01:24:45.350    NULL
10743   01:25:37.240    NULL
10743   NULL    01:27:40.257
10743   NULL    01:27:41.200
16300   NULL    01:27:45.257
.. Now I want them merged..

Comment: Updated query check now ?

Comment: it works.. but its taking the first IN and last OUT right... I need the records in between the 1st in and last out... I am really sorry to trouble you like this..